# Infopath Linked Fields

Tags: function, infopath2010

Pretty new to Infopath here and I can't seem to google this right so i'm going straight to my last option!

I'm building a form in which a Dropdown list needs to change dependant on the value of another dropdown list

So If X = 1, Then Y = 3 etc.

I'm just not aware of the functionality of Infopath and how I can get something like this working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be described at the following post:

[Auto-populating an Infopath form after selecting a drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636194/auto-populating-an-infopath-form-after-selecting-a-drop-down)

Essentially you will be using the rules manager to indicate that when a field equals something it will populate another field with data related to it. Think of it as more complex vlookup. Additionally, the verbage you would want to use to google more on the subject would be along the lines of "infopath  auto-populate field based on another fields value".