# Auto-populating an Infopath form after selecting a drop down

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I currently have two lists one titled 'Book of Work' which holds details around on-going projects and the other titled 'Book of Work Amendments' which are requests submitted by users to change project details (through an infopath form).

There is a column in the BoW Amendments list entitled 'Select Project' which has a lookup to 'Project Name' in the BoW list. The aim is that when a user chooses an option from the 'Select Project' drop-down, other fields in the form such as 'Project Manager', 'Project Description' will be automatically populated with data from that row in the BoW table.

I have connected both Sharepoint Lists as data connections with BoW Amendments being the primary and BoW the secondary. If we take the Project Manager field as an example the method I have attempted is as follows:

. Create a rule with condition **Select Project is not blank**

. Action - Set a field's value: **Field: Project Manager** (BoW Amendments - Primary)  **Value: Project Manager** (BoW - Secondary) **Add Filter**: **Project_Name** (BoW - Secondary) = **Select Project** (BoW - Primary)

Currently this is not populating the field when the project is selected in the drop down, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, just a little off. You want a rule on the Select Project dropdown when "field changes".

Next create your set field value action to whatever field you want; in this case, the Project Manager field

Now set the 'value' to Project Manager (BoW-Secondary). Add filter project_name (BoW-secondary) = Project dropdown (Main)

Basically that last filter is saying "get the project manager from BoW-secondary where the project name is equal to the selected value of the project dropdown list.

Comment: I managed to get to this last week finally! But thanks for your answer.